# Showing web camera through web interface (Python, CherryPy, OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, cherrypy

I want to show OpenCV processed image with web interface (made with CherryPy). Code below works fine:

```
import cherrypy
import cv2


class Picture(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

@cherrypy.expose
def index(self):
    _, image = self.cam.read()
    _, data = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
    cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
    return data.tostring()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '127.0.0.1', 'server.socket_port': 80, })
    cherrypy.quickstart(Picture())
```

However: I would like to embed the image in html so I can (for example) add another image or other data to the same page.

I have tried the following code:

```
import cherrypy
import cv2


class Picture(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

@cherrypy.expose
def index(self):
    _, image = self.cam.read()
    _, data = cv2.imencode('.jpeg', image)

    return """ <html>
    <head>
    <title>CherryPy static imagl</title>
    </head>
    <html>
    <body>
    <img src=" """ + data + """:image/jpeg" />
    </body>
    </html>"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '127.0.0.1', 'server.socket_port': 80, })
    cherrypy.quickstart(Picture())
```

But this gives the following error:

```
 <img src=" """ + data + """:image/jpeg" />
 TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'numpy.ndarray' objects
```

Converting the numpy arry to a string using the following code also does not work (it gives no error but displays only characters):

```
<img src=" """ + data.tostring() + """:image/jpeg" />
```

Anyone who can give me some more insight? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The following code does the trick :)

```
import cherrypy
import cv2
import base64


class Picture(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        _, image = self.cam.read()
        _, data = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)

        jpeg_base64 = base64.b64encode(data.tostring())

        return """
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" />
        <title>Cherrypy webcam</title>
        </head>
        <html>
        <body>
        <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,%s' />
        <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,%s' />
        </body>
        </html>
        """ % (jpeg_base64, jpeg_base64)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '127.0.0.1', 'server.socket_port': 80, })
    cherrypy.quickstart(Picture())
```

This code displays the same picture two times. and the:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" />
```

refreshes the code every second.

Comment: why does it have 2 img tags ?

Comment: To demo that you can display two files. I actually use two webcams :)